# Vue: issue when using method to dinamically render a responsive nav

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created an isResponsive() method to know if current screen is mobile or not, using this method I want to dinamically render some elements inside my nav or not, **sadly this only works on initial render, id I change screen size my nav elements don't update, even though I added an event listener for "resize" event** in my component mounted hook.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my componenet:

```
<template>
<nav v-scroll-apply-class="'LAYOUTnav_fixed'" class="LAYOUTnav1_maincontainer">
    <div class="LAYOUTnav1_links_container" v-if="!isResponsive()">
        <a class="LAYOUTnav1_links_link fs_small hover_slide_center" v-for="link in visibleLinks" :key="link.name" :href="link.url" :class="{ active_nav : meta.activeNav == link.name}">{{ link.name }}</a>
        <button class="LAYOUTnav1_links_button_container" type="button" @click="TOGGLE_CART_TAB()" v-bg-color="'rgb(10,10,10)'">
            <i class="LAYOUTnav1_links_button_icon fas fa-shopping-cart fs_bigger"></i>
            <span class="LAYOUTnav1_links_button_text fs_normal" v-if="cartItems.length != 0">{{ cartItems.length }}</span>
            <span class="LAYOUTnav1_links_button_text fs_normal" v-if="cartItems.length == 0">¡El carrito esta vacio!</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="LAYOUTnav6_responsive_top_container" v-if="isResponsive()">
        <a class="LAYOUTwrapper_row" href="/admin" v-if="globals.auth.privileges > 1">
            <i class="LAYOUTnav6_responsive_top_icon fas fa-cog fs_small"></i>
            <span class="LAYOUTnav6_responsive_top_text fs_small">Administrar</span>
        </a>
        <a class="LAYOUTwrapper_row" href="/descuentos/canjear/codigo" v-if="globals.auth.privileges > 1" v-del>
            <i class="LAYOUTnav6_responsive_top_icon fas fa-euro-sign fs_normal"></i>
            <span class="LAYOUTnav6_responsive_top_text fs_small">Canjear código</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
</template>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script>
import { isResponsive } from '../../includes/utils.js';
export default {
name: 'LAYOUTnav6',


computed: {

},


mounted() {
    console.log(this.$options.name+' component successfully mounted');

    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        isResponsive();
        console.log('resized');
    }, true);
},


methods: {

    isResponsive:isResponsive,

}


};
</script>
<!--STYLES-->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

And my isResponsive method:

```
export function isResponsive() {

    let viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;

    if (viewportWidth < 765) {
        //on mobile
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        //not on mobile
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resize event handler is firing on resize, but the result is not binding against any reactive property of your component, neither a data attribute nor a computed property.

```
data: function() {
           return {
               isResponsive: false,
      },
},
mounted() {
    console.log(this.$options.name+' component successfully mounted');
    var vue = this;
    vue.isResponsive = isResponsive();
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        vue.isResponsive = isResponsive();
        console.log('resized');
    }, true);
},
```

In your template markup use `<div class="LAYOUTnav1_links_container" v-if="!isResponsive">`